# Browser only allowing 3 tabs to connect to local server via Socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a React App that currently in development. I use `socket.io` to connect the frontend to my server file which I'm running locally.

I opened multiple tabs (including incognito) so I can simulate multiple people using it at the same time and the browser hangs up on the 4th window. I can open up to 3 just fine. When I introduce the 4th one I can either not get the React app loaded or I load it and it hangs up when I try to do anything that emits a socket action.

I did notice that I can open a 4th window in Firefox no problem. So it seems like it's a Chrome / Browser thing limiting me to 3 socket connections from a single browser.

Any ideas on what's going on? I don't even have a ton of emits being sent out. I really don't think it's my server or client code. I tried turning on `multi-plexing using

`const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', { forceNew: true });`

in my Client code (React) but it didn't fix the problem until I started using Chrome and Firefox together to keep Chrome under 4 tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a hard-coded limit of open connections to a server in Chrome.

It's actually 6 open sockets per host (https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3339263?hl=en). However, to confuse things, I suspect that you're using something like hot-reloading, which *also* uses a socket (hence why each page takes up two sockets, not just one).

The only thing you *could* do, depending on your architecture, is spawn multiple servers on different ports (then you'd be able to have 6 per port).

Alternatively, as you've found, you can use another browser that does not enforce this limit.

Comment: I am hot-reloading as I'm using CRA for the front-end and nodemon for the server file. I didn't realize that this hot-reloading took up an extra socket. 

Now I thought Chrome's 6  ports was only for HTTP purposes. I didn't know it also applied to web sockets.